# GNU Make: Test if either OR variables are null or undefined

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

As I understand it **$(and** should short circuit and return "" if **either** VAR1 **OR** VAR2 is null or undefined. This should make the **ifeq** true and print the message. Otherwise if **both** variables have values it should return the value of VAR2 which is obviously not "" making the **ifeq** evaluation false and not printing the message.

It's not working. What am I missing?

```
ifeq ($(and $(VAR1),$(VAR2)), "")
$(info *************************************)
$(info *        To avoid prompts set       *)
$(info *          VAR1 and VAR2            *)
$(info *       prior to running make       *)
$(info *************************************)
endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Basically: all arguments have contents, then the expansion is the contents of the last one.  Otherwise, the expansion is empty.

Note, *none* of these situations result in the expansion being the value `""`, which is not empty it's two `"` characters in a row.  Make doesn't do anything special with quotes: they are just like any other character.  So, saying **ifeq (,"")** is *always false*.  You don't want to compare a string with `""` unless you want to check if the string literally contains two double-quote characters in a row.

So I think (if I understand you correctly) you want:

```
ifeq ($(and $(VAR1),$(VAR2)),)
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works perfectly by leaving it empty!! The GNU Make Manual (under _Functions for Conditionals_) says literally _"If an argument expands to an empty string the processing stops and the result of the expansion is the empty string. "_. In every other language on the planet, the empty string is usually "" or ''. So I went through the manual, back to _Conditional Parts of Makefiles/Syntax of Conditionals_ and, in effect, the explanation is right there when it talks about using strip to avoid pitfalls like mine, and uses this as an example `ifeq ($(strip $(foo)),)`.

Comment: An empty string is the same in all languages: it's a string that contains no characters.  The way you _represent_ that string is different in different languages.  A pedantic point I know.